# Is there a way to save/export to clipboard?

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, inkscape

Word 2013-Inkscape bad interoperability brought me to this question. When I want to use my Inkscape graphics in word, I either have to:
1. Save as... -> .EMF;
2. Export PNG
...then navigate in word or file explorer to the file location and insert or copy paste it. Also, there is an exported file that has little value to me left after this process.

Is there a general way (system-wide active software) or at least Inkscape plug-in that would allow redirecting of any file operation (save/load) directly to clipboard? It would be an incredibly useful tool but I cannot find software like this.

Comment: I was able to create shapes in Inkscape, select them (more than one) and use Edit, Copy, then use Paste to place them in a Word 2010 document. Is this particular sequence broken in 2013?

Comment: This approach only pastes a very low resolution rasterised image of the selection from Inkscape.

Comment: Did you try Ditto at this link http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/